# Class vector initialisation

Tags: c++, class, oop

I want to create a class which has an array attribute. The class looks like:

```
class MyVector {
  private:
     int m_vector[];
  public:
  /* Here I would have a constructor and other functions*/
 }
```

Can I initialise an object of the class in the following manner?

```
MyVector vec={1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: you either need to specify the size of the array in class definition, or use vector<int>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code this way:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

class MyVector
{
  private:

  int m_vector[5]; //  if you use a static array you need specify its size
  public:
    MyVector(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
      int i = 0;
      for (auto value : l) {
        if (i - 1 >= 5)
          break;
        m_vector[i++] = value; 
      }
    }
};
```

Use `std::initializer_list<T>`, that defined in `<initializer_list>` header